# robocopy differential backup batch script

Tags: batch-file, backup, robocopy

I wrote a differential backup script. I had to use robocopy because my teacher said so. Sadly I dont know much about batch scripts or robocopy, so I would appreciate it of someone could tell me what im doing wrong. I want to make a differential backup of a fullbackup every 60 minutes and log it. The problem is that exactly nothing happens when i execute the script.

```
set fullbackup=C:\Users\raffael\Desktop\fullbackup
set differential_backup=C:\Users\raffael\Desktop\differential_backup
@Echo off
robocopy.exe "%fullbackup" "%differential_backup" /e /copyall /mir /mot:60 /r:100 /w:10 /log+:C:\Users\raffael\Desktop\log.txt
```

Comment: What did you do? What shall it do? What does it actually do? Where's the discrepancy and what's the actual problem? Answer those questions in your question (edit it accordingly)

Comment: Your command line works correctly here. Of course nothing is printed to the screen due to the absence of `/tee` switch but the files are copied and the log file is updated.

Comment: it doesnt work for me nothing gets copied

Comment: did you tried and get final solution? what is `/mot:60` ?